# Output is appearing in the wrong order using Scala in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I started on Scala this morning, and wrote up the following:

```
package tutorial
object Main {

    class Tutorial(message: String = "") {
        var a = message

        def speak() =
            println(a)
    }

    def main(args:Array[String]) =
        println("Hello world")

        val t = new Tutorial("BARK!")
        t.speak()

        println("World hello")
}
```

I expected the output to be:

```
Hello world
BARK!
World hello
```

but for some reason, it's outputting:

```
BARK!
World hello
Hello world
```

Which makes 0 sense to me. I looked up "Scala buffering problem", but it didn't list anything relevant, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.
This is being output to Scala Eclipse's Console. I tried using REPL, but it gives me an error on the first line (`package tutorial`), even though it compiles fine in Eclipse.

Can someone shed some light on what's going on?

Comment: Hint: indentation doesn't introduce a new scope in Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Travis Brown suggested, you're missing the `{}` in your main function.

So what you code should look like is:

```
package tutorial
object Main {

    class Tutorial(message: String = "") {
        var a = message

        def speak() =
            println(a)
    }

    def main(args:Array[String]) = {
        println("Hello world")

        val t = new Tutorial("BARK!")
        t.speak()

        println("World hello")
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd add that the original code compiles, because `val t = ...`, `t.speak` and `println(...)` are valid class-level statements and are executed as part of the object's instantiation, hence before the method is executed.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand a couple of things though. Why didn't the `main` declaration result in a compilation error? If the following statements were interpreted as being in the class body, that would mean that `main` was empty. Shouldn't that have given an empty method body error? And why did the print statements execute in that order? Even if they weren't in the scope that I was anticipating, shouldn't they have still been executed top-down?

Comment: Main isn't empty. The `println("Hello World")` is the body of main. The other statements are executed first (hence the "BARK!" and "World Hello"), then main is called.